# Jenkins connector in Microsoft team is not visible

Tags: jenkins, microsoft-teams

i am trying to integrate jenkins build with Microsoft team and for that i used team 365 connector plugin. But the problem is that i can not find jenkins connector in microsoft team, i tried to search for jenkins in team connector but can not find it.

Comment: Could you please ask your tenant admin to [Allow external apps in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/enable-features-office-365#apps)?

Answer (score 3):

It's there. You can install it from here: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104380360?tab=Overview

If it doesn't show up in your version of Teams, it's because your administrator has disabled apps or Jenkins specifically. More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/admin-settings.

Comment: i guess only premium or paid version of MS team have admin and mine is not paid one so don't have admin access. how can I enable jenkins in such case

Comment: @Prajwol Did you figure out a way to add Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

Now, you don't need anymore the "Jenkins connector" installed on Teams.

You could use the "Incoming Webhook" of Microsoft to get hook url.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors

See https://teams.microsoft.com/l/app/203a1e2c-26cc-47ca-83ae-be98f960b6b2?source=app-details-dialog